# Passing struct by reference causing AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, reference, struct, pinvoke

Yet another one of my P/Invoke questions! I have this C function:

```
int _ei_x_new(ei_x_buff* x);
```

Essentially, it initializes a new buffer struct. In C#, I have this:

```
[DllImport(EIDLL, EntryPoint = "_ei_x_new")]
public static extern int ei_x_new(out ei_x_buff x);
```

`ei_x_buff` is pretty simple:

```
typedef struct ei_x_buff_TAG {
    char* buff;
    int buffsz;
    int index;
} ei_x_buff;

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct ei_x_buff {
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string buff;
    public int buffsz;
    public int index;
}
```

But when I do this:

```
ei_x_buff buffer;
Ei.ei_x_new(out buffer);
```

I get an **AccessViolationException**:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Do I need to alloc some memory or something? It's such a simple piece of code that I can't see any glaring problems with it.

**EDIT:** Native code for `_ei_x_new`:

```
// In my wrapper library
DLL_EXPORT int _ei_x_new(ei_x_buff* x) {
    return ei_x_new(x);
}

// In external library being wrapped
int ei_x_extra = 100;

int ei_x_new(ei_x_buff* x)
{
    x->buff = malloc(ei_x_extra);
    x->buffsz = ei_x_extra;
    x->index = 0;
    return x->buff != NULL ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things

- Use out not ref in the PInvoke signature as you want data marshalled in both directions (into and out of the native function)
- Can you post the native signature as their could be an issue with the definition.  In particular the buff member

**EDIT**

Just to eliminate one possibility, switch the buff member to be typed IntPtr with no attributes.  If that doesn't cause a crash then it's likely a marshalling issue with the string type.

Comment: The P/Invoke signature uses out already. If you meant "ref not out", it produces the same result. The native signature is given in the question: int _ei_x_new(ei_x_buff* x);

Comment: Oh, you mean the struct's native signature? I've edited my question to show it.

Comment: Changing it to IntPtr stopped the exception. Can I leave it like that, or do I need to use another type?

Comment: @David, I would go that route and add a wrapper property which calls Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi on the value. Curious, how is the string allocated in native code?  The memory I mean

Comment: I've updated the question with the full code for _ei_x_new. Doesn't look like it's working with a string at all, really...

Answer (score 0):

Do yo have mark the buffer as pinned in memory using the [fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21(VS.80).aspx) statement:

example:

```
// assume class Point { public int x, y; }
// pt is a managed variable, subject to garbage collection.
Point pt = new Point();
// Using fixed allows the address of pt members to be
// taken, and "pins" pt so it isn't relocated.
fixed ( int* p = &pt.x )
{
    *p = 1; 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be relevant in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work with string too, if you just initialisze the buffer properly on the C side. Keep in mind that the buffer malloc returns may contain garbage, so you should add something like

if (x->buff) x->buff[0] = '\0';

Another thing you may want to double check is that you're using the same calling convention on the native and managed side. The CLR assumes _stdcall unless you specify something else in the DllImport attribute.