# Take Address of Managed Structure

Tags: c#, pointers, structure

(I am coding in C#)

I want to pass a pointer to structure through an API.
Say structure is,

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet= CharSet.Ansi)]
      public struct PassThisStruct
        {
           public Int32 Param1;
           public Int32 Param2;
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=13)]
           public Char[] OutputData;

        };
```

Now the API declaration is:-

```
unsafe public delegate Int32 MyAPI(Int16 Something, PassThisStruct* StructPtr);
```

i.e. I want to pass Structure pointer to Structure.

I made a delegate for this API and then retrived address from DLL and stored it in Function Pointer.
But When I try to compile, it gives me error at the *delegate declaration* that, "Cannot take address of, get size of, or declare pointer to managed space".

So how should pass the pointer?
I do know that I can use "ref" but this API is written in C++ and it wants a structure pointer. If I use ref I can't pass Null and I am also getting error as "AccessViolationException" (That's one more big problem for me!). So I would use ref only if I can get rid of AccessViolationException.

One more question, Can I pass Null in this case?? If Yes, How?

Regards!

Comment: My Question regarding "AccessViolationException": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958119/pinning-a-structure-to-avoid-accessviolationexception

Comment: I cant see why you should get that error. There is no 'managed' types used. Perhaps it is the `ByValArray` causing issues. Also make sure the `struct` is `fixed` or a local variable.

Comment: What do you mean by `delegate declaration`? I dont see any such thing in your code.

Comment: My bad.... The API declaration is delegate (Corrected in Question). And I can understand, "Also make sure the struct is fixed or a local variable"

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are suing constant char array. So I would rewrite this structure as:

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet= CharSet.Ansi)]
  public unsafe struct PassThisStruct
    {
       public Int32 Param1;
       public Int32 Param2;
       public fixed char OutputData[3];
    };
```

1)
       Then I would use IntPtr ptr = Marshal.StructureToPtr(...);

```
   unsafe public delegate Int32 MyAPI(Int16 Something, PassThisStruct* StructPtr) would change to:
   public delegate Int32 MyAPI(Int16 Something, IntPtr StructPtr)
```

2)
      I have not tried but I think that you could do:

```
  unsafe void MyMethod()
  {
     PassThisStruct s = new PassThisStruct();
     PassThisStruct* sPtr = (PassThisStruct*)s;

     myAPI(12, sPtr);
  }
```